# Autocomplete search with previews: should I load all products beforehand and only search in the front-end?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, search, debouncing

I'm building a search mechanism with Laravel and Vue in which a panel is shown displaying the thumbnail of each of the products as you type. So, as soon as you type more than 3 letters, for each letter it's updating that list asynchronously.

My question is: should I preload all of the results and only process this list in the front-end? Would it be quicker?

The biggest problem is if I debounce the typing process to, say, only search each 0.5s, the UX gets a bit compromised since the up-to-date list seems "slow". So loading all the results beforehand could be a good idea, however, does it even make sense to dump thousands of records into Vuex for this?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against pulling all of your records in Vuex at once. You could use debounce in such a way that it gets executed immediately, and further presses wait 0.5s before firing a search. It's also possible to send the query to your backend, and have it hit an elasticsearch index.